# libGDX AssetManager - not working on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a problem with a libGDX game. I have some texture to load, so , when I start the  game on android mode is showing me like a blank screen for around 15 seconds. I try to use AssetManager, to load texture on another class and then to use it, but now, it doesn't working on Android devices (it shows me the loading bar, and when it is full, it exit from the game), it works only on desktop mode.

Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Practically is the same code engine, just I don't load the sprites from gdx.files.internal I load them from AssetManager.

like this i load:

```
   game.manager.load("angel/angelAnimation0.png", Texture.class);
    game.manager.load("angel/angelAnimation1.png", Texture.class);
    game.manager.load("animations/animatie.png", Texture.class);
    game.manager.load("animations/shakeAnim.png", Texture.class);
    game.manager.load("bottles/animatieSticla1.png", Texture.class);
       game.manager.load("bottles/animatieSticla2.png", Texture.class);
       game.manager.load("bottles/animatieSticla3.png", Texture.class);
       game.manager.load("bottles/animatieSticla4.png", Texture.class);
       game.manager.load("bottles/animatieSticla5.png", Texture.class);
```

and so on..

and like this i get :

```
taPourAnimation1 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla1.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        taPourAnimation2 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla2.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        taPourAnimation3 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla3.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        taPourAnimation4 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla4.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        taPourAnimation5 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla5.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        taPourAnimation6 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla6.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        taPourAnimation7 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla7.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
        taPourAnimation8 = game.manager.get("bottles/animatieSticla8.txt", TextureAtlas.class);
```

etc.

any advice ??

Comment: How can you load .png and get .txt?

Comment: problem solved.

I forgot to change the initializer of some sprites, so i laod them into assetmanager, and after in the game i load them again from gdx.files.internal

10x.

Comment: @Harry


I have to load a lot of things so I post just a sample to have an idea about what I am doing.